# Account for clustered standard errors in mediation analysis in R

Tags: r

I have an experimental set-up that requires that I account for the clustered nature of the data. I currently do this using `lm_robust` in the `estimatr` library in R

```
library(estimatr)
fit_main <- lm_robust(change_score ~ sex * treatment_dummy * moderator_idx,
             cluster = team_id,
             se = "stata",
             data = data_full)
```

I'd like to explore whether a variable `moderator_idx` causally mediates the relationship between the `treatment_dummy` and `change_score`

I do that like so:

```
library(mediation)
med.fit <- lm(moderator_idx ~ treatment_dummy * sex, data = data_full)
out.fit <- lm(change_score ~ sex * treatment_dummy * moderator_idx, data = data_full)
med.out <- mediation::mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat = "treatment_dummy", mediator = "moderator_idx", robustSE = TRUE, sims = 1000)
summary(med.out)
```

However, the `robustSE` flag is not the same as cluster-robust standard errors. Is there a way to account for clustering while using the `mediation` library? In other words, is there some way to take the standard errors from the lm_robust object and input them into the mediation library?